# How to play an image sequence within a div using a jQuery vertical scrolling type effect

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, sequence

I"ve been experimenting with jQuery to animate page elements base the vertical scroll position 
 som ething similar to the [Nike Better World](http://www.nikebetterworld.com) site. I have a pretty firm grasp on how to do this. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to also play an image sequence. For instance, one of the divs that is a PNG (say a shoe) would be png sequence instead, as the user scrolls down, the image would play.

Answer (score 1):

Nike better world is using [parallax scrolling](http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm) , but if you want to swap images while scrolling i recommend to take a look at this [scrolling video](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-interactive-street-view-jquery) , [jsMovie plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jsmovie/) and have a look at this [javascript animated image sequence](http://www.simg.de/jsMovie/example/index.html) . Hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd bolt it to an incremental scroll shift, and toggle an active/selected class down through the sequence, to show/hide each frame. A great example here: http://discover.store.sony.com/tablet/#intro You'd want to focus your efforts on creative load management, as those png's would start to add up quickly. I think I'd rather work with inline images beyond a certain physical size. But if your anim/images are small, shifting a background sprite would be more efficient. I get no points for solution, sans code, but this is how I would approach it nonetheless. A separate example can be found at the smartcarusa.com site, in the 4th or 5th section. Here, they are achieving the exploded skin effect via shifting divs' x- and y- pos on scroll.